# Regular Expression for checking Character and Number

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string say, AAA123 (3 Characters followed with 3 Numbers)
I want an regular expression, that actually matches this pattern.
I have tried this so far,

```
Regex.Match(stringToBeMatched, @"\d{2}[a-zA-Z]").Success;
```

But its not helping, any help would be good.

Comment: Could you show a pattern?

Comment: @roydukkey The thing is like, 3 Characters followed by 3 Numbers. Will update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what do you actually mean by *matches this pattern*:

1. `@"^AAA123$"`             - exactly `AAA123`, no alternatives
2. `@"^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$"`    - three capital letters A..Z followed by 3 digits
3. `@"^[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{3}$"` - three letters (A..Z a..z) followed by 3 digits

To test I suggest `Regex.IsMatch` which looks more convenient than your version.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(stringToBeMatched, @"^[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{3}$")) {
  //TODO: put a relevant code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is three alfa and three numbers? [a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}